# EXTJS Is there a way to get ajax firstly from 1 URL and post dirty data to other?

Tags: extjs

My question is so. I have 2 different URLs on the server. 1 is for returning xml to client and second for handling dirty data from client. Is there a way to tell ajax proxy on my model to behave such a way? Thanx in advance.

Comment: You can dynamically change the url on your proxy between requests if that's what you mean?

Comment: See the `api` config.

Answer (score 0):

It is a usual practice to have several urls for different CRUD operations and Ext counts with that. See [api config option](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/ext/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-cfg-api) of proxy for details.